# Top and bottom fixed height with fluid height middle

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

What I am going to ask is something that I did using javascript but I do want to achieve it **with css only** (if possible )

Here is the scenario:

I have a DIV element which height is ***h*** px. This very DIV element has *3 childs* which are DIV elements too. Their purpose is the following:

First DIV element is ***k*** px height and is attached to the top of the parent container. Its height is constant.

Second DIV element is ***n*** px height and is attached to the bottom of the parent container. Its height is constant.

Third DIV element is ***h - (n+k)*** px.

What I want is **when I resize the parent div** ( which is a floating box ) to automatically keep the third DIV element h - (n+k) px.

Is this possible to be achieved with ***css only*** ?

Answer (score 6):

Yes use `calc()` function:

for your 3rd div set `height` CSS property as:

```
height: calc(h - n - k);
```

Answer (score 6):

If you plan on supporting [browsers that don't support `calc()`](http://caniuse.com/#feat=calc) here is an approach without it.

The point is to use absolute positioning, padding (the same height as the attached top and bottom elements) and `box-sizing:border-box;` :

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/webtiki/cc3vdyyr/1/)**

```css
html,body,.wrap {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
div {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.wrap {
  position: relative;
  width: 50%;
  padding: 50px 0 80px;
  border: 5px solid tomato;
}
.one,.two {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  border: 5px solid teal;
}
.one {
  height: 50px;
  top: 0;
}
.two {
  height: 80px;
  bottom: 0;
}
.three {
  height: 100%;
  background: gold;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="one"></div>
  <div class="two"></div>
  <div class="three"></div>
</div>
```

---

### Edit :

Here is a bonus without the `box-sizing` property and only absolute positioning :

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/webtiki/Lxpdo2vq/2/)**

```css
html, body, .wrap {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.wrap {
    position: relative;
    width: 50%;
}
.one, .two, .three {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    background: teal;
}
.one {
    height: 50px;
    top: 0;
}
.two {
    height: 80px;
    bottom: 0;
}
.three {
    top: 50px;
    bottom: 80px;
    background: gold;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
    <div class="one">... content 1 ...</div>
    <div class="two">... content 2 ...</div>
    <div class="three">...content 3 ...</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

An alternative to `calc()` is to use [flexboxes](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/). These don't couple the heights together so if you ever change the heights of the header and footer, you don't need to update the CSS for your other element.

Here is a basic example:

```js
$('button').on('click', function() {
    $('.container').height(function(i, v) {
        return v < 200 ? 250 : 150
    });
})
```

```css
.container {
    float:left;
    height:150px;
    width:300px;
    background-color:#000;
    /* set as a flex container laid out in a column (top to bottom) */
    display:flex;
    flex-direction:column;
}

/* content div, flex auto fills the remaining height */
.container div {
    background-color:#0f0;
    flex:1 1 auto;
}

/* top red div, fixed at 50px */
.container div:first-child {
    flex:0 0 50px;
    background-color:#f00;
}

/* bottom blue div, fixed at 50px */
.container div:last-child {
    flex:0 0 50px;
    background-color:#00f;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
    <div>Header</div>
    <div>Content</div>
    <div>Footer</div>
</div>
<div><button>Resize Container</button></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You may use `calc` to achieve this. For example:

```
div {
 height: calc(h - n - k);
}
```

For further reading, check out this great tutorial on `calc()` :
http://webdesign.tutsplus.com/tutorials/calc-grids-are-the-best-grids--cms-22902

Answer (score 1):

Here is demo [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/u7y24wpx/)

HTML:

```
<div id="main">
    <div id="a"></div>
    <div id="b">Hello</div>
    <div id="c"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#main{height: 100%;background:red;}
#a{height: 100px;background:blue;}
#c{height: 50px;background:green;}
#b{height: calc(100% - 150px});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `calc()`.  Here is a [working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/54drf135/)

Remember to wrap use parenthesis in the correct place (e.g `calc(200px - (50px + 50px))`)

```
#parent {
    width: 100px;
    height: 200px;
}

#div1 {
    height: 50px;
    background: red;
}

#div2 {
    height: 50px;
    background: blue;
}

#div3 {
    height: calc(200px - (50px + 50px));
    background: green;
}
```

Also be sure to [check browser support](http://caniuse.com/#search=calc)

Comment: What if the parent div is resizable and its height is dynamic? Will the middle div's height change when i resize the parent?

Comment: @JoroSeksa If you use a percentage to define the height of the parent div rather than 200px then yes